# How to create multiple Response Transformers on wiremock

Tags: java, wiremock

How do I go about creating multiple transformers on wiremock? I've seen on the documentation that you can call two response transformers on one stub but I'm not sure how you go about creating the second response transformer as well as giving it a name?

So this is the **Second transformer I've created**

```
public class test2 extends ResponseDefinitionTransformer{
 String message;
    boolean value;




  @Override
    public ResponseDefinition transform(Request rqst, ResponseDefinition rd, FileSource fs, Parameters prmtrs) {
         message =  rqst.getBodyAsString();
         value = validateXMLSchema("xxx", message);
                      System.out.println("SECOND TRANSFORMER EXECUTED");
        System.out.println("THIS IS THE CONDITION OF THE VALUE: " + value );
         if(SchemaMatches){

        return new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withBody("XSD SCHEMA MATCHES")
                    .build();      
        }else{
              return new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                    .withStatus(404)
                    .withBody("MISMATCH")
                    .build();

         }
    }
  @Override
public boolean applyGlobally() {
    return false;
}
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "tests";
    }

}
```

This is the **first** transformer I've created:

```
public class Stub extends ResponseDefinitionTransformer {
@Override
    public ResponseDefinition transform(com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.Request rqst, ResponseDefinition rd, FileSource fs, Parameters prmtrs) {
      message =  rqst.getBodyAsString();
if(MandatoryFieldsExist){
        return new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withBody("MANDATORY FIELDS PRESENT ")
                    .build();      
        }


else{
            return new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                    .withStatus(404)
                    .withBody("MISMATCH")
                    .build();

        }

    }

    @Override
public boolean applyGlobally() {
    return false;
}

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "example";
    }
```

Finally, this is the code in my main method to call the transformer:

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.options().port(8080).extensions(Stub.class, test2.class));
        WireMock wireMockClient = new WireMock();
        wireMockServer.start();               
        stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/user/test"))               
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                        .withBody("XML RECIEVED")
                        .withTransformers("example","tests")

                )
        );
```

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: just create another class with a different transformation

Comment: @MykolaGurov I did that, but It doesn't seem to pick it up. I'll edit the post to show what I've done

Comment: you should also override `isGlobal` to return false

Comment: @MykolaGurov,Yep I did do that, I set it to false, but it's not working. I tried to print out some statements to see if the compiler reaches the second class, but it doesn't appear to reach it as nothing is printed out in the compiler

Comment: you have one stub, so every match will call both transformers. you should either make distinction on stubbing level or have one transformer doing different actions depending on the request

Comment: @MykolaGurov I'm not quite sure I understand, could you show me an example of the code? Are you saying, create a second stub in the main method and assign it the second transformer?

Comment: I mean at the example you gave all two transformers are been applied with the latest overwriting the effect of the former

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referring to class in wireMockServer e.g: Stub.class use constructor
e.g : **new Stub() , new test2()**

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.options().port(8080).extensions(new Stub.(),new test2()));
        WireMock wireMockClient = new WireMock();
        wireMockServer.start();               
        stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/user/test"))               
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
                        .withBody("XML RECIEVED")
                        .withTransformers("example","tests")

                )
        );
```